# Display formatted hash in browser using Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, hash, pretty-print

I am writing a ruby gem that will create an HTML file. I am writing a hash to that. I wanted this hash to be displayed like a formatted json structure. But when I open it on browser it just display as a String. How can I format the hash and display it on the browser.

I tried the following things,

```
file.write(my_hash.to_json)

file.write(PP.pp(my_has))

file.write(JSON.pretty_generate(my_hash))
```

Comment: what is the file extension? .html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_hash.map do |key,value|
  "#{ key }:#{ value }"
end.join( '<br>' )
```

or

```
my_hash.map do |key,value|
  "<span>#{ key }:#{ value }</span>"
end.join( "\n" )
```